# Mlogit crashes when testing CSV File

Tags: r, regression

I am new to this forum and to R so please bear with me. I will try to make my post as detailed as possible!

The R I am using is version 2.9.2 on mac 10.6.8.

I am currently running a mlogit model on some csv data. I have successfully ran the analysis on a test file that I obtained on the internet which contained 9000 rows & 10 columns of numerical data. I was able to get all the coefficients and P values that I required without any problems and in a very efficient time.

However, having learnt the basic's using my test file I then tried to repeat the analysis on my data csv. This csv has been deliberately formatted in the same way as the test file and have less rows (6000) and less columns (6). Though when I run the same summary on the mlogit model it freezes and becomes unresponsive.

Could it be the formatting of the file? As the size is smaller so I don't think it's a memory issues.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1):

You could quickly check out the formatting possibility by opening up both csv files in a text editor.  Perhaps one is comma delimited and the other tab delimited.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the data you have read in right before you call mlogit.

`summary`, and 'head' are useful functions to look at data frames but you should also look at each variable in more detail.

Is it exactly as it should be?

Do all the arguments to the mlogit function correspond exactly to the data you're giving it, rather than to the test data?